# iMac Mouse Stuck in Scroll Mode

Tags: imac, mouse, error, macos

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help. My 2009 27" iMac suddenly starting having mouse issues, rendering it almost unusable. The best way to describe it would be as if the mouse were permanently stuck in "scroll down" position.

I've tried a Logitech mouse, HP mouse, and magic mouse - all connecting in different modes (bluetooth, USB and USB dongle).

Here's a screencast of the issue in action:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGZ-oIhkE60&feature=youtu.be

Any possible solutions? Thanks!

Comment: It's more like your down arrow is stuck; that's what would scroll menus without scrolling web pages Try tapping or holding  the up arrow & see if it stops or reverses. [Or try a different keyboard, even if it's a Windows one]

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the answer. Having different issues with different keyboards, but found software to modify and disable that key. Thanks for your two cents!